# AIX 6.1 , tar issue

Tags: tar, aix

AIX6.1, I use java to execute a tar command to extract a tar package. one stange thing I met is that some files with long name in thi tar package failed to be extracted to where they should be. but occurs at current working folder. and the file owner of these files are not correct too.

I googled and found that there many post for use GUN tar instead to avoid long file name issue. but I am sure this is not the same issue as I met.

is there anyone know why this happen? any tips are appreciate much. thanks.

Comment: another thing I noticed is that file path and name of those files that not be extracted to correct place are between 120~125 characters.

Comment: Have you tried GNU tar at all? If not, do that first.

Comment: This issue does not always happen, I cannot reproduce it every time. I have tried the GUN tar, it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The man pages are pretty instructive on this topic.  Probably your tar file is not strictly POSIX compatible.  On AIX:

```
The prefix buffer can be a maximum of 155 bytes and the name buffer can
hold a maximum of 100 bytes. If the path name cannot be split into
these two parts by a slash, it cannot be archived.
```

The Linux man page for GNU tar says it can handle a variety of tar file format variants.  One of these is the 'ustar' POSIX standard, which appears to be the one handled by AIX tar.  There is a separate gnu format, which is the default for GNU tar.

I'd suspect you're opening a GNU tar archive with a tar tool which only understands the POSIX standard, and it can't quite cope.